# Where can I find the dependencies of desktop flow in power Automate?

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I had a problem with Power Automate Desktop. We needed to download reports for lots of companies every Monday, so We set up a special process for each company. Then, We made another process to run all these company tasks together on Mondays. But something went wrong with one company's process, so I made a copy to fix it. When I finished fixing the copy, I accidentally deleted the original one. Now, when I try to run the process that handles all the companies together, it says there's a problem. It's saying something about missing parts it needs to work properly. I think it's because I deleted that original process by mistake. I'm not sure how to fix it without making things worse.

[This is the error that I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHFwQ.png)

Comment: There's no fancy way to do this. You have to go through the entire flow manually and look for references to flows by their GUID and compare that to the GUIDs of flows you still have. When you find a GUID reference that you can't find a matching flow for, you have your culprit.